# How to print a region in views.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a views-view-unformatted--viewsname--attachment.tpl.php. I want to print region in this file.

I added

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
   if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region('regionname')) {
      $vars['region'] = $blocks;
  }
}
```

to `template.php`.

and added

```
echo render($region);
```

to `views-view-unformatted--viewsname--attachment.tpl.php` but print nothing.

What is wrong? How can I print region in `views.tpl.php`?

i tested this with [mytheme_preprocess_html and html.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/printing-regions-in-html-tpl-php) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new region in your theme's .info file.

   ```
   regions[RegionName] = Region Name
   ```
2. Insert following code in your
   views-view-unformatted--viewsname--attachment.tpl.php template file
   to insert region between views rows:

   ```
   print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('RegionName'));
   ```
3. And then put your block into this region.

For more reference go to [this](http://618designs.co.uk/blog/embedding-region-between-views-rows).